# find string with a pattern at the end regex python

Tags: python, regex, string, compilation

I want to check if a string ends with a "_INT".

Here is my code

```
nOther = "c1_1"

tail = re.compile('_\d*$')
if tail.search(nOther):
    nOther = nOther.replace("_","0")
print nOther
```

output:

```
c101
c102
c103
c104
```

but there may be two underscores in the string, I am only interested in the last one.

How can I edit my code to handle this?

Comment: what are the possiblities `c1__x`,`c_1_x`.. etc. what is your expected output for these??

Comment: that is possible. The output file is a spss mdd (if thats useful)

Comment: i mean what output do expecting for two underscores, do you expecting `c1__1` -> `c101`, `c_1_1` -> `c101`, `c_1_2` -> `c102` etc..

Comment: ohh my bad. c1__1 > c1_01, c_1_1 > c_101, c_1_2 > c_102, so basically I want to replace the last underscore with a "0"

Comment: would something like this work better: re.sub(r"\.(?=[^.]*$)", r'_', s) for s in nOther

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using two steps is useless (check if the pattern matches, make the replacement), because `re.sub` makes it in one step:

```
txt = re.sub(r'_(?=\d+$)', '0', txt)
```

The pattern use a lookahead `(?=...)` *(i.e. followed by)* that is only a check and the content inside is not a part of the match result. (In other words `\d+$` is not replaced)

Comment: This is what I was looking for while writing my answer. Thanks for the precision.

Comment: @Rod: I see. To avoid to search the last underscore, the pattern use the *end of the string* anchor and the fact that only digits are allowed after the last underscore.

Comment: @Rod: however adding `(.*)` at the begining of the pattern is not a bad idea because it might avoid a lot of tests for the regex engine due to the fact that `.*` is greedy and that the regex engine only need few backtracking steps to obtain a match. (must be tested with real strings)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte why `(.*)` is not a bad idea??. your regex check for the existence of `_` and number at the end. and will replace `_` with 0, seems like this is the best answer.

Comment: @suhail: because the regex engine will test the pattern character by character from left to right. For a string like `abc_1` you will obtain a fast result with my pattern (the three first characters will fail), but for the string `aaaa_aa___a...a__a_aa_aaaa_1`, `(.*)` will match all the string (a fast step) and the regex engine need only two backtracking steps to obtain the match with `_(\d+)$`. (with my pattern, the regex engine will backtrack on each underscore, except the last.)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to capture everything that is not the last underscore and rebuild the string.

```
import re

nOther = "c1_1"

tail = re.compile('(.*)_(\d*$)')

tail.sub(nOther, "0")
m = tail.search(nOther)
if m:
    nOther = m.group(1) + '0' + m.group(2)
print nOther
```